# Relation of webforms in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, webforms, razorengine

I am a beginner to MVC technology and have few questions.

1) How can I webforms in MVC and why/when should I used it ?

2) If we can build a application using razor view engine then why webform engine is provided ? If it is, we can continue to use traditional web forms.

3) Can I combine razor/aspx view engine in one project.

Coz I can see we can add WebForm/master pages by right clicking in View folder ....

Any help on this appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I'll recommend you reading some ASP.NET MVC book instead. Because it will give you basic understanding of MVC concept. But still:

1. You can't use webforms in MVC. Because it's completely different approach;
2. MVC gives you more flexibility over markup, you can customize your application easily. Again read about MVC pattern. Webforms instead are faster to develop, but heavier in terms of size and have some ugly things like viewstate;
3. Yes, you can. But in different pages, not in the same page.

Comment: Thats fine... Even I have came to the approach before reading this links.                                                                                              http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx
https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/mixing-web-forms-and-asp.net-mvc/; But then it seems confusing to me ??

Comment: @Rohit, but what for do you need mixing this two approaches? I'm corcerned that the only time you need mixing is step by step refactoring webforms to MVC in some king of continious refactoring.

Comment: Concerned because we can simply add WebForm/master/ascx etc in a views folder ? in that case how we can hanld it ?

Comment: Can you explain your question more detailed? I don't think I got it right.

Comment: Means lets say i have created a project using razor view engine.. So I can work easily with cshtml files. Parallely I can add the web forms in the same project.. So it means that I am using Razor and web form engine together in same project. How can work on this ?